# How can I applying 1 class from an array to each li in order?

Tags: jquery, html, css

**html**

```
<ul class="logoUl">
    <li class="orange"></li>
    <li class="blue"></li>
    <li class="green"></li>
    <li class="pink"></li>
</ul>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
if (selectedCategory == 'currentAll') {

    var strString = "orange,blue,green,pink";
    var strArray = strString.split(',');

    $.each(strArray, function (index, value) {
        $("ul.logoUl > li").addClass(value)
    });
}
```

there are 4 li's in the ul.logoUL making an image liek this[image]
Some times the logo gets a background color which will reset the colors to gray [image: like so]

currently my code does this doesnt reset the colors back[image]

**Question:**

How can iterate through `li`'s one at a time while adding one class at a time in hopes to gain the original colors scheme via classes?

Comment: +1 for nicely present the question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var strString = "orange,blue,green,pink",
    strArray = strString.split(',');

$("ul.logoUl > li").each(function (index, value) {
    $(this).addClass(strArray[index]);
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/j4qqS/5/)**

#### Without loop:

```
var strString = "orange,blue,green,pink",
    strArray = strString.split(',');

$("ul.logoUl > li").addClass(function (index) {
    return strArray[index];
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/j4qqS/2/)**

#### Note

As you're changing `class` to each `li` to give them similar `background` sometimes, so when you want to give them their original color scheme again, it would be better to remove previously assigned color `class` first and then assign original `class` again like following:

```
var strString = "orange,blue,green,pink",
    strArray = strString.split(',');

$("ul.logoUl > li")
    .removeClass() // first remove previous class
    .addClass(function (index) { // then add new class
        return strArray[index];
    });
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/j4qqS/7/)**

Comment: @Matthew Harwood without loop approach you can do it in second approach

Comment: props on those symantics & logic I really learned a lot from this.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
if (selectedCategory == 'currentAll') {

    var strString = "orange,blue,green,pink";
    var strArray = strString.split(',');

    $.each(strArray, function (index, value) {
        $("ul.logoUl > li").eq(index).addClass(value)
    });
}
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/j4qqS/

Comment: is this the best way to make the array also? or is spliting the best method of making string array?

Comment: Yeah Based on what you have in the string, you have to `.split` to split it into an array.